# cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'target' (position 2) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, pytorch

Data preparation, and building the model：

```
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
data = dataset.data
target = dataset.target
data_tensor=torch.from_numpy(data).float()
target_tensor=torch.from_numpy(target).long()

model = nn.Sequential(
    bnn.BayesLinear(prior_mu=0, prior_sigma=0.1, in_features=4, out_features=100),
    nn.ReLU(),
    bnn.BayesLinear(prior_mu=0, prior_sigma=0.1, in_features=100, out_features=3),
)
cross_entropy_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
klloss = bnn.BKLLoss(reduction='mean', last_layer_only=False)
klweight = 0.01
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

Run the model: Error occurred

```
for step in range(3000):
    models = model(data_tensor)
    cross_entropy = cross_entropy_loss(models, target)
    kl = klloss(model)
    total_cost = cross_entropy + klweight*kl

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_cost.backward()
    optimizer.step()
  
_, predicted = torch.max(models.data, 1)
final = target_tensor.size(0)
correct = (predicted == target_tensor).sum()
print('- Accuracy: %f %%' % (100 * float(correct) / final))
print('- CE : %2.2f, KL : %2.2f' % (cross_entropy.item(), kl.item()))
```

```
TypeError 
----> 3     cross_entropy = cross_entropy_loss(models, target)
TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'target' (position 2) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray
```

I copied code from a web-learning page, but it shows the attached error, any suggestions? many thanks !!

Comment: TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'target' (position 2) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong variable for target.

```
cross_entropy_loss(models, target)
```

would be

```
cross_entropy_loss(models, target_tensor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tensors are more generalized vectors. Thus every tensor can be represented as a multidimensional array or vector, but not every vector can be represented as tensors.

Hence `numpy` arrays can easily be replaced with `tensor` , but the tensor can not be replaced with `numpy` arrays

The `crossentropyloss` expects a tensor to be passed as argument but your `target` variable is an `numpy` array so it's raising the error. Pass `target_tensor` variable instead of `target` it will solve the issue.

Read more about Cross Entropyless [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)

Comment: thank you for your explanation!!!  Could you please check out my other questions about target # is out of bounds ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969094/indexerror-target-11-is-out-of-bounds-cross-entropy

Comment: If the answer is correct, Please select it, as that will help future viewers instantly find the answer. Thanks.