# IndexError: Target 11 is out of bounds. cross-entropy

Tags: python, pytorch, bayesian, cross-entropy

How can I change the attached model to fit my dataset for the Bayesian model? my data include 5 variables and 32 results

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    bnn.BayesLinear(prior_mu=0, prior_sigma=0.1, in_features=5, out_features=100),
    nn.ReLU(),
    bnn.BayesLinear(prior_mu=0, prior_sigma=0.1, in_features=100, out_features=3),
)
```

```
cross_entropy_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
klloss = bnn.BKLLoss(reduction='mean', last_layer_only=False)
klweight = 0.01
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

Next is to run the model

```
for step in range(3000):
    models = model(data_tensor)
    cross_entropy = cross_entropy_loss(models, target_tensor)
    kl = klloss(model)
    total_cost = cross_entropy + klweight*kl

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_cost.backward()
    optimizer.step()
  
_,predicted = torch.max(models.data, 1)
final = target_tensor.size(0)
correct = (predicted == target_tensor).sum()
print('- Accuracy: %f %%' % (100 * float(correct) / final))
print('- CE : %2.2f, KL : %2.2f' % (cross_entropy.item(), kl.item()))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19752/2114183600.py in <module>
      1 for step in range(4000):
      2     models = model(data_tensor)
----> 3     cross_entropy = cross_entropy_loss(models, target_tensor)
      4     kl = klloss(model)
      5     total_cost = cross_entropy + klweight*kl

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
   1148 
   1149     def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1150         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1151                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1152                                label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   2847 
   2848 

IndexError: Target 11 is out of bounds.
```

data_tensor.shape:torch.Size([640, 5])

target_tensor.shape:  torch.Size([640])

data properties:

```
data_tensor=torch.from_numpy(data).float()
target_tensor=torch.from_numpy(target).float()
target_tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0,  1,  2,  3,
         4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
        22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
         8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
        26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
        30, 31,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0,  1,
         2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
         6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
        24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
        28, 29, 30, 31])
```

I am not sure what's wrong with my target_sensor and cross_entropy_Loss. Target sensors are repeat numbers between 0-31, for 20 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same question with you, please check whether the output number in final Linear part of your model is equal to the num_classes.
I am not good at English, please ignore the gramme problem hhh